# how to use first post image as thumbnail on wordpress

Tags: post-thumbnails

how can i set my thumbnail to use the first image on my post?
most time i use bbcode( [img] ) to place images on my post, i want them to be use as well,

have tried so many suggestion, but none meet my needs,

below are some of the codes that have tried.

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
  the_post_thumbnail();
} else { ?>
  <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/default-image.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

i try adding this on my function.php

```
//function to call first uploaded image in functions file
function main_image() {
$files = get_children('post_parent='.get_the_ID().'&post_type=attachment
&post_mime_type=image&order=desc');
if($files) :
  $keys = array_reverse(array_keys($files));
  $j=0;
  $num = $keys[$j];
  $image=wp_get_attachment_image($num, 'large', true);
  $imagepieces = explode('"', $image);
  $imagepath = $imagepieces[1];
  $main=wp_get_attachment_url($num);
    $template=get_template_directory();
    $the_title=get_the_title();
    print "<img src='$main' alt='$the_title' class='frame' />";
  endif;
}
```

Comment: Fix your code please if you want help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this function, in your functions.php file.

```
// automatically retrieve the first image from posts
function get_first_image() {
    global $post, $posts;
    $first_img = '';
    ob_start();
    ob_end_clean();
    $output = preg_match_all( '/<img .+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches );
    $first_img = $matches[1][0];
    if ( empty( $first_img ) ) {
        // defines a fallback imaage
        $first_img = get_template_directory_uri() . "/images/default.jpg";
    }
    $first_img = '<img src="' . $first_img . '" alt="Post Image" />';
    return $first_img;
}
```

This function search for first image tag in content and returns it. Then in your theme you can call image like this.

```
<?php
    if ( get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id ) != '' ) {
        the_post_thumbnail();
    } else {
        echo get_first_image();
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks @robert , d code work well, but it did nt use image posted with bbcode(img) as thumbnail, pls i need the one dat can use image from external link as thumbnail, tanks